# Writing a database logger from Play - how to handle errors?

Tags: java, log4j, playframework

I'm writing a database log4j appender in Play.

On its `append()` method, it creates a new instance of a model entity Log4jLine, and `saves()` it via JPA.

This works fine on debug/info logs. However, exceptions are not logged.
There is a call to this appender from framework code, but I suspect it is not working because the JPA session is not valid at this point.

How would I adapt the code to support this use case?

```
public class DBAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
        Log4jLine logLine = new Log4jLine(...);
        logLine.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it, but it's happening because if you throw an exception from one of your controller methods, Play Framework will mark the transaction as setRollbackOnly.

Comment: @Todd - I should write the log in a separate transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per our conversation above I was curious about how to do this and was able to get this to work.  Essentially, you need to create a new EntityManager and fully manage it yourself.  Calling any of the Play built-ins (.save(), .merge(), etc) will cause them to use the EntityManager that Play sets up for you.  However, if you revert to standard JPA calls, it will work.

```
// Mapped in routes file as GET /exception        
public static void exceptionTest() {
    RuntimeException e = new RuntimeException("This is a test");
    logException(e);
    renderText("You are here");

}

private static void logException(RuntimeException e) {
    EntityManager em = JPA.newEntityManager();
    Notification n = new Notification();
    n.setMessage(e.getMessage());

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(n);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    throw e;
}
```

This is just a quick and dirty experiment to prove the point.  You'll obviously need to handle exceptions and failure cases in logException() that I'm not handling.  And just for clarity, Notification is a basic object in my project I was able to use for this quickly.

Hope that helps!